# When creating an RMI application on two different machines Client and Server Where should we Define our Interface Client side or Server side?

Tags: java, interface, rmi

I want to write an RMI application using two laptops which adds two numbers? i have made one laptop as my server and another laptop as my client. when we want to define the interface which is extending from Remote interface on which machine should i define this interface the client side or the server side? please help.

i Have made an RMI application using one machine it works fine I have defined the Interface in the same package but when i work on different machines it does not work.

```
public interface AdditionI extends Remote {
    public int add(int x ,int y) throws RemoteException;
}

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AdditionI {

   public Server() throws RemoteException {}

   @Override
   public int add(int x, int y) throws RemoteException {
       return x+y;
   }

   public static void main(String ar [])throws RemoteException {
       try
       {
           Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2177);
           reg.rebind("Add", new Server());
           System.out.println("Server is ready");
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Error "+ e);
       }
   }
}



public class Client {

    public static void main(String ar[])throws RemoteException {
        try {
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",2177);
            AdditionI ad = (AdditionI)reg.lookup("Add");
            System.out.println("REsult:"+(ad.add(10, 5)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error"+e);
        }
    }

}
```

when i run this code on the same machine it works fine the result of the method add is displayed, but on different machine it displays the following message.

`java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`

Comment: Have you tried compiling the AdditionI interface sepparately as a Jar and then including said jar on the server and client computers?

Comment: Neither. Use a shared package.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should we Define our Interface Client side or Server side?

Simple: you need the interface on **both** sides.

The Client knows that interface, and basically it is the "only thing" it knows: there is some interface that defines the behavior (the methods) that the client code can use.

The Server knows that interface and **implements** it.

That interface is the basic thing that "links" client and server (conceptually). They both know that there is some interface `AdditionI`. The client will need it so it

- first identify a service that supports that interface
- when such an service is found, the client knows how to *invoke* the corresponding add method

The server on the other hand uses the interface to register its implementation as a service ... that clients then can call.

Therefore, you basically have **three** different parts in your source code:

- *common*: that contains that `AdditionI` interface
- *client*: the additional code required to identify and later use that addition service
- *server*: the additional code to implement and register the service

And note: that exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is really basic. It tells you that the JVM running some code did not find some class.

In other words: your classpath setup is somehow broken. Simply research that exception (you can find endless endless documentation about such basic things, see [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-how-to-solve-class-not-found-exception/) for example). Most likely, it boils down to: making sure that some .class files are in the classpath ... where you need them. And the first part already tells you where which classes need to go to!

Comment: i defined the same interface on both machines but it gave me the exception which i have mentioned in my question. should i create a jar file from the interface and add it on both the machines or i need to define it on both sides?

Comment: @ijazahmadkhpalwaak `ClassNotFoundException` says you *didn't* define the same interface on both machines.